# Alternative to MPI_Sendrecv_replace

Tags: c, mpi

I am trying to get an alternative code to

```
 if(rank %2==0 && rightNeighbour != MPI_PROC_NULL)
     MPI_Sendrecv_replace(&bufferRight[0], len, MPI_DOUBLE, rightNeighbour, 1, 
                 rightNeighbour, 1, MPI_COMM_WORLD, &status);
 else if(rank%2 ==1 && leftNeighbour != MPI_PROC_NULL)
     MPI_Sendrecv_replace(&bufferLeft[0], len, MPI_DOUBLE, leftNeighbour, 1, 
             leftNeighbour, 1, MPI_COMM_WORLD, &status);

 if (rank % 2 == 1 && rightNeighbour != MPI_PROC_NULL)  
    MPI_Sendrecv_replace(&bufferRight[0], len, MPI_DOUBLE, rightNeighbour, 1,
             rightNeighbour, 1, MPI_COMM_WORLD, &status);
 else if (rank % 2 == 0 && leftNeighbour != MPI_PROC_NULL)   
    MPI_Sendrecv_replace(&bufferLeft[0], len, MPI_DOUBLE, leftNeighbour, 1, 
             leftNeighbour, 1, MPI_COMM_WORLD, &status);
```

using `MPI_Send` and `MPI_Recv` but it seems it's deadlocking. Any easy way of doing the same with `MPI_Send` and `MPI_Recv` ?

I have tried using

```
if(rank %2==0 && rightNeighbour != MPI_PROC_NULL){
    MPI_Recv(&bufferRight[0], len, MPI_DOUBLE, rightNeighbour, 1, 
         MPI_COMM_WORLD, &status);

    MPI_Send(&bufferRight[0], len, MPI_DOUBLE, rightNeighbour, 1, 
         MPI_COMM_WORLD);
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This code:

```
if(rank % 2 == 0 && rightNeighbour != MPI_PROC_NULL)
   MPI_Sendrecv_replace(&bufferRight[0], len, MPI_DOUBLE, rightNeighbour, 1, 
                       rightNeighbour, 1, MPI_COMM_WORLD, &status);
else if(rank % 2 == 1 && leftNeighbour != MPI_PROC_NULL)
   MPI_Sendrecv_replace(&bufferLeft[0], len, MPI_DOUBLE, leftNeighbour, 1, 
                        leftNeighbour, 1, MPI_COMM_WORLD, &status);
```

is equivalent to:

```
if(rank % 2 == 0)
{
   MPI_Send(&bufferRight[0], len, MPI_DOUBLE, rightNeighbour, 1,
            MPI_COMM_WORLD);
   MPI_Recv(&bufferRight[0], len, MPI_DOUBLE, rightNeighbour, 1,
            MPI_COMM_WORLD, &status);
}
else if(rank % 2 == 1)
{
   double *temp = malloc(len * sizeof(double));
   MPI_Recv(temp, len, MPI_DOUBLE, leftNeighbour, 1,
            MPI_COMM_WORLD, &status);
   MPI_Send(&bufferLeft[0], len, MPI_DOUBLE, leftNeighbour, 1,
            MPI_COMM_WORLD, &status);
   memcpy(&bufferLeft[0], temp, len * sizeof(double));
   free(temp);
}
```

Note that order of the send and receive calls is reversed in the odd ranks. Also, the receive uses a temporary buffer in order to implement the  semantics of `MPI_Sendrecv_replace`, which guarantees that the data in the buffer is first sent and only then overwritten with the received one.

Note that the check whether a rank is not `MPI_PROC_NULL` is pointless since a send to/receive from `MPI_PROC_NULL` is essentially a no-op and will always succeed. One of the key ideas of the semantics of `MPI_PROC_NULL` is to facilitate the writing of symmetric code that doesn't contain such `if`'s.

Comment: @_Hristo Why are you not using the temporary buffer when `(rank %2 ==0)` ?

Comment: @Manolete: because `MPI_Send` is a blocking operation - it only returns once the content of the buffer has been consumed by MPI and thus it is safe to pass the same buffer to `MPI_Recv`, which will overwrite the previous content.

Answer (score 2):

You better use `MPI_Irecv` and `MPI_Isend` rather than the blocking calls (`MPI_Recv` and `MPI_Send`). Then, after issuing the communication routines, simply wait for the requests using the `MPI_Waitall` (or two calls to `MPI_Wait`). However, to do this you cannot use the same buffer (i.e. the replace) -- you need to have two separate buffers -- because otherwise they would get corrupted as the buffers might get the content replaced before the actual send.

Let `A` be the incoming buffer and `B` the outgoing buffesr, your code should look something like

```
if(rank %2==0 && rightNeighbour != MPI_PROC_NULL){
    MPI_Request req[2];
    MPI_Status status[2];

    MPI_Irecv (&A, len, MPI_DOUBLE, rightNeighbour, 1, 
      MPI_COMM_WORLD, &req[0]);
    MPI_Isend (&B, len, MPI_DOUBLE, rightNeighbour, 1, 
      MPI_COMM_WORLD, &req[1]);

    /* A */

    MPI_Waitall (2, req, status);
}
```

Note that in `/* A */` you can take advantage to do some computation while the communication is *flying*. Also, the error checking is omitted in the code -- you better check all return codes for the MPI calls.

Answer (score 1):

Although **probably the best way to proceed is to follow Harald's** suggestion on using `MPI_Isend` and `MPI_Irecv`, there's one alternative which might not work depending on the case.

For small buffer sizes, some MPI implementations follow what is known as *eager mode*. In this mode, the message is sent regardless the receiver is already waiting for the message or not. The send buffer data is copied to a temporary buffer and, since the user's send buffer is available after the copy is done, `MPI_Send` returns **before the communication has actually been completed**.

This is a bit risky, since for large messages MPI usually works in *rendezvous* mode, which actually **synchronizes** both ends, so the following code would produce a deadlock as well:

```
if(rank %2==0 && rightNeighbour != MPI_PROC_NULL){

    MPI_Send(&bufferRight[0], len, MPI_DOUBLE, rightNeighbour, 1, 
         MPI_COMM_WORLD);

    MPI_Recv(&bufferRight[0], len, MPI_DOUBLE, rightNeighbour, 1, 
         MPI_COMM_WORLD, &status);
}
```

In `MPI_Recv`, however, the reception buffer is (obviously) not available until the data has already been received.

Additional info on [MPI performance tips](https://computing.llnl.gov/tutorials/mpi_performance/#Protocols).